# google play service not bind with titanium studio android

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-android

OS: Mac OS X - Yosemite

Using Titanium Studio

**Problem**

google_play_service not imported properly into titanium studio' android project.

**Error when running the project**

```
[ERROR] :  /Users/myself/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/Project/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml:27: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

**Note**

SDK already having google_play_services library into {SDK}/extras/google/

If you have any solution then please share here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is this in the simulator?

Comment: Did you try to remove the version tag (cause it seems you had put one) and let Titanium uses the last one it will find ?